# Configuring Datadog IIS integration

Tags: iis

I have installed Datadog and added integrations with IIS to monitor performance issue.
Now in agent.log i keep receiving this error.

```
2019-08-29 14:56:04 EET | CORE | WARN | (pkg/collector/python/datadog_agent.go:108 in LogMessage) | (iis.py:97) | Site u'Default Web Site' not in expected_sites.
```

My conf.yaml under iis.d folder is as follows

```
init_config: ~
instances: 
  - 
    host: "."
logs: 
  - 
    path: "C:\\inetpub\\logs\\LogFiles\\W3SVC1\\u_ex*"
    service: iis
    source: iis
    sourcecategory: http_web_access
    type: file
sites: 
  - "Default Web Site"
```

I would appreciate any help about this please.
Thanks in advance.
Nader

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is coming from the `sites` parameter.

As you may see in the [template configuration file for Datadog-IIS integration](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/5e2509d725f2e8aabbfe4e37b1abb6a6d7a91c89/iis/datadog_checks/iis/data/conf.yaml.example#L25):

First, it needs to be nested under the instance you defined, so the correct configuration file would be:

```
init_config:
instances: 
  - host: "."
    sites: 
      - "Default Web Site"

logs: 
  - type: file
    path: "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex*"
    service: iis
    source: iis
    sourcecategory: http_web_access
```

What i'm also suspecting here is that the site name you entered might not be the right one.

As the `sites` parameter is optional, you only need it if you want a specific list of sites from your IIS to be monitored. 
If you remove this parameter you will get all your sites monitored, and all metrics will be tagged by `site` so within Datadog you will be able to focus on the one you care the most.

Could you try the configuration below and see if it works?

```
init_config:

instances: 
  - host: "."

logs: 
  - type: file
    path: "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex*"
    service: iis
    source: iis
    sourcecategory: http_web_access
```

Best,
Pierre

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.